# Why is my program a resource hog even though I set THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN?

Tags: c++, windows, openmp

I have a program structured as follows, and it's a massive CPU hog.  IO slows down for the whole system, I can hardly move the mouse pointer...

...why?  I thought THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN should prevent this?

```
#pragma omp parallel 
{
    SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN);

    #pragma omp for 
    for (...)
    {
        doTruckLoadsOfComputation();
        if (omp_get_thread_num()==0)
            doTinyAmountOfIO(); //progress indicator
    }
    SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_END);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Adding `SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL);` fixes the CPU hogging issue but the question still stands, why wasn't background mode alone sufficient?

Comment: What happens if you bring another window to the foreground / minimise the application?

Comment: I can't, the other window doesn't even come to foreground.

Comment: Dumb question: What OS are you running on? [`THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN`/`END` isn't supported prior to Vista](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so an old WS03 machine probably wouldn't work. It might help to actually check the return value from `SetThreadPriority` to make sure it succeeded. It's also unclear whether background mode actually affects CPU scheduling priority; it looks like it's an addon that changes I/O priority (which other settings don't), but the exact behavior isn't properly documented.

Comment: Background vs. Foreground is a bit more nuanced than the `SetThreadPriority` implies. This old article, although dated now, explains it better: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/259025 . A 'background' thread can still steal 100% CPU

Comment: @ShadowRanger not a dumb question, but Win7

Comment: I have just noticed `doTinyAmountOfIO`. How many times do you call this? What happens if you remove it?

Comment: I just noticed in Remus' link above that even a tiny amount of IO will cause a priority boost, which may explain *everything*.  (figuratively speaking)

Answer (score 0):

*This is too long for a comment*

You have simpler alternatives: [`START /BELOWNORMAL <yourexe>`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297.aspx) can run any arbitrary process at lower priority, w/o modifying the source code.

If you want to do it from within the app, a much better alternative is to us a [Job object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161(v=vs.85).aspx). Use the [`JOBOBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448384(v=vs.85).aspx) for fine grained control of how much CPU your app can consume. The most important benefit of JOBs vs. thread affinity is that job restrictions apply to the entire process *and* to any process spawned by the controlled process.